# DVI-D over HDMI fundamental problems?

Tags: hdmi, dvi

**Is DVI-D over HDMI *inherently* a lossless setup?**  Assuming there are no specific driver bugs or wire problems or hardware bugs, **would such a setup have a degradation in video quality or capability?**

In my case, I plan for

```
DVI-D PC connection ↔
  DVI-D-to-HDMI adapter ↔
  HDMI 35 foot cable ↔
  DVI-D-to-HDMI adapter ↔
DVI-D monitor connection
```

I'm hoping there isn't some fundamental problem with this type of DVI-D connection. An example [DVI-D to HDMI adapter](http://a.co/eLqyvkD).

Comment: Why are you trying to convert twice? DVI-D to HDMI is a native same-signal connection, so passive adapters are all you need. But with any link change you're degrading the line consistency and quality. Have you just looked into a 35' DVI cable?

Comment: > "Why are you trying to convert twice?"  I need to use a small cable for a narrow cable hiding apparatus.  DVI-D cables are too big.  HDMI cable can be flat and small.  Such an HDMI cable will fit within the cable hiding apparatus.